# How to hide a field without hiding the sub fields/levels in Pivot Table?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, pivot-table

I'm trying to create a pivot table in Excel 2010. I have the following fields that I added for the pivot table.

> User
>
> Internal id - user id
>
> Date
>
> Leave
>
> Type
>
> Amount (Days)

All are in the row labels except the amount (days) which I put in the Values and made its settings to sum.

What I want to achieve is that since I included the date just to categorize it by date but I want it to be hidden without hiding the sub fields (which are the leave and the type - which are under the date). Is there a way for me to hide the date without hiding the fields under it and without removing the 'categorized by date'? I hope you get me. It's kinda hard for me to explain.

Answer (score 0):

Either drag the Date field to the Filters pane (which turns it into a PageField) or simply hide the entire column that the Date field is in.